# UIScrollView + UIPageControl + UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

How do you make a menu like in Cut the Rope game. Image below:

[image]

I am able to make three images slide horizontally but failed to make it as a button.
Though I don't need it to be fancy as the game's, but just a simple button.

Do I need to stack three different Views with its respective buttons inside UIScrollView? I am leaning towards doing it programmatically though.

Code: http://pastebin.com/ikrJ1U7w

Comment: you want to show images with button background?

Comment: Come again? I'm sorry, but I don't get you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually a `UIScrollView` which containing `UIButton` of custom type & has image on that. Below that is `UIPageIndicator`.

You can create it as below, althouh also search for

- How to create `UIButton` programatically to add on scrollview

In your view controller,

In `viewDidLoad`, in scrollView add the buttons.

```
    UIScrollView *scrollView = // initalize & set frame as per ur req
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    float x = 0.0;
    float y = 0.0, width = 320.0;

    float height;

    for (int j = 0; j <= numberofpagesYouwant; j++)
    {
        CGRect frame;

        UIButton *button = // Create a button at here;

        frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height); // Use this as your button frame

        [scrollView addSubview:button];

        [button release];

        x = x + width;
    }

     scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(numberOfPagesYouHave * 320, heightOfYourScrollView);
}



-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;

    if(page != activityIndicator.currentPage)
    {
        NSLog(@"now page change:%d",page);
        [self changePageIndicator:page];   
    }
}

-(void)changePageIndicator:(int)index
{
    activityIndicator.currentPage = index;
}

- (void)setNumberOfPages:(int)numPages1
{
    activityIndicator.numberOfPages = numPages1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I am pretty sure this is just several buttons placed on top of some sort of a scrollView. (most likely done programatically).

Comment: Yes, what? That these buttons are on top of each other?

Comment: No, they are all on the same scrollView with their frames positioned a certain number of points to the right of each other (most likely 320 because that is the screen width).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Anyways, I have done that on my code. However, these images are not UIButtons.

Comment: They are images that I can swipe from left to right, and/or vice versa.